# jquery with react comparison example

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Hi I do understand theoritically that why using jquery with react is not good for DOM. But can anyone give me a practical example with the code of react alone and react with jquery and show how is it not good?

Comment: I dont want any opinionated answers. I just need a practical example as I am not able to create one or think of one myself

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, React use a "virtual DOM" to know the current state of the DOM and update only what is necessary. In short, the shadow DOM is just a giant object stored in memory in which React will check what changed to update the DOM. It is possible because in React, you declare in the `render` method what you want to display.

Jquery conflict with that since you don't use the render to "declare" what you want to display and it might cause side-effect.

Comment: Can you please give an example?